# Manifest merger Failed after adding Google Firebase Authentication

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, android-manifest, manifest-merging

After adding Firebase Authentication to app implementation I got a Manifest Merger failed error.

> "Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs"

I tried using different versions of the authentication but didn't work. 
The solutions for the same type of problems in StackOverflow didn't work for me.

I tried the suggested changes in Merged manifest but this error came up again

> Merging Errors: Error: tools:replace specified at line:6 for
>    attribute android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified app
>   main manifest (this file), line 5 Error: Validation failed, exiting
>   app main manifest (this file)

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">
        <activity android:name=".VerifyEmployeeID"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".SignUp" />
        <activity android:name=".login" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

```
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'


    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'

    //firebase database
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

I need to get rid of this error.

Comment: Please add the code snippet that you have added into the firebase for authentication

Comment: Migrate to androidx it will fix your manifest merger issue: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: Latest firebase libraries supporting androidx package that's the reason showing  error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are using simple dependency or androidx support dependency. That's why this error occurs.

Remove below the line in **Manifest.xml**

> tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"

Use this dependency in **build.gradle**

> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
>
> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'

Remove all androidx dependency in your **build.gradle** file and sync project.

Comment: I did the modification you suggested and it worked. What I want to know is how the version of the firebase-core and firebase-auth can do such a difference? What is the basis of using different versions for different problems?

Comment: My suggestion is to use the latest dependency. But last month Firebase migrates their latest dependancy in androidx and we use third-party dependency which is not used androidx dependancy that's why we have to downgrade the firebase dependancy. Android now migrate to all dependency in androidx in future. so don't worry after someday this problem resolved. for more information visit the Android developer blog. Happy coding.

Comment: This answer is really helpful! BTW: starts from June 17, 2019, the firebase SDK requires app migrated to androidX: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2019-06-17

Comment: Glad to know this answer is useful for you... @LiuWenbin_NO.